# How to make relation counting in Excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, count, counting

I have a table with **employees**, **id**, **name**, **date** and **time** they attend and leave like this:

[image: image from link]

What I need now is to make a new table based on the old table to *count* how many employee attended on each date. I did something using an `if` statement like this:

```
=IF(B2=total!C:C;COUNT(total!D2:D154))
```

But sometimes it doesn't work.

Please, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This is commonly handled with a PivotTable.  If you want to use a formula, you should check out `COUNTIF` which will count employees based on the date matching the desired date.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that one employee can attend only once a day (I see you only have one line for one employee), the following formula might count how many employees attended on some particular day:

`=COUNTIFS(C:C,C1,D:D,">0")`

In my data, the column A holds ID numbers; B - names; C - dates; D - time when they attended, or no value (the cell is left blank) if the employee did not attend. If I used your screenshot data, the cell C1 would represent the value of 02/09/2013.

`COUNTIFS` is used to count values which meet several conditions. In our case we have 2 conditions. 

*First*, the part `C:C,C1` checks how many dates like in `C1` there is in total in the column `C:C`.

*Then* the part `D:D,">0"` counts how many cells in the column `D:D` are not left blank (employees actually attended).

If both conditions on the same row are satisfied, then the row is counted, otherwise it's not counted. The formula processes every row in the sheet, as we have defined so in our conditions: `C:C` and `D:D`.